# SQL- HAVING Clause Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, having, having-clause

I'm trying to use the `MAX()` function as a subquery to filter results of my greater query by the last couple of whole years. I realized this was a little bit more complicated than what I initially thought it would need so I created a much simpler query to test out what I would need to do with the `HAVING` clause in order to get it to work.

I've checked these two posts but it didn't really help ([SQL, HAVING clause explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813634/sql-having-clause-explained), [SQL: HAVING clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745308/sql-having-clause))

I don't think my understanding of the `HAVING` clause is correct because I'm not sure why it's not working. Would someone be able to help and explain?

Note: `[Fiscal Year]` is `NVARCHAR` so I figured converting it to `INT` might work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT

D.[FISCAL YEAR]

FROM [Dates] AS D

GROUP BY D.[Fiscal Year]

HAVING CONVERT(INT,D.[Fiscal Year]) >= MAX(CONVERT(INT,D.[FISCAL YEAR])) -2
```

These are my results:

```
(No column name)
2015
2014
2013
2012
2016
```

These are the results I should get:

```
(No column name)
2015
2014
2016
```

Comment: Why not use a Where statement instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be done better in the `WHERE` clause. This solution isn't optimal, but here's what you can do.

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT D.[FISCAL YEAR]
FROM [Dates] AS D
      WHERE CONVERT(INT,d.[Fiscal Year]) 
             >= (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT,[Fiscal Year])) -2 from Dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is you are grouping by the year, thus the max will always be the same as the year for that group.

Here's one option using `window functions`:

```
select distinct fiscalyear 
from (
    select fiscalyear, max(fiscalyear) over () maxfiscalyear
    from dates 
) t 
where fiscalyear >= maxfiscalyear - 2
```

I don't see the need to use the `convert` function here either, but if you need to, you can add it back.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9ab84/1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!